# flyway authentication with certificate

Tags: postgresql, flyway

I have a postgres database that uses SSL for connection. Currently, I have a  certificate CA file which I use to create the connection from PGAdmin. I am trying to use Flyway for migration. But I can't find any environment variable or a way to pass my certificate file for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the path to your CA Certificate via the `sslcert` connection parameter in your PostgreSQL JDBC URL. In Flyway, you provide this URL via the `flyway.url` configuration item, like so:

```
flyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres.server.address:5432?sslcert=./test/client.crt
```

[See the Flyway `flyway.url` configuration docs here.](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configfiles)

[See the PostgreSQL JDBC driver docs here.](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html)

Comment: I keep getting this error  when I do as you suggested above FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "3.26.75.105"", user "admin", database "postgres", SSL off

Comment: Try adding `&sslmode=require&ssl=true` to the connection string, does that help?

Comment: After those two parameters I am now getting.WARNING: Discarding INCOMPLETE dataSource configuration! flyway.url must be set.
ERROR: Unable to connect to the database. Configure the url, user and password!